# Spring boot micrometer register cache metrics

Tags: spring, spring-boot, prometheus, metrics

I have a problem with creating metrics for 2 instances of the application.
I created metrics for hazelcast cache metrics using

```
 HazelcastCacheMetrics.monitor(prometheusMeterRegistry, (IMap<?, ?>) cache.getNativeCache());
```

and when I run 1 instance of application everything work properly but when I run 2 instances i got error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastCacheMetricConfig': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Prometheus requires that all meters with the same name have the same set of tag keys. There is already an existing meter named 'cache_size' containing tag keys [cache, cacheManager, name]. The meter you are attempting to register has keys [cache].
```

Or when I change registered metrics into

```
@Autowired
private CacheMetricsRegistrar cacheMetricsRegistrar;

cacheMetricsRegistrar.bindCacheToRegistry(cache, Tag.of("instance", podName));
```

I have this error

```
 Error creating bean with name 'hazelcastCacheMetricConfig': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Prometheus requires that all meters with the same name have the same set of tag keys. There is already an existing meter named 'cache_size' containing tag keys [cache, cacheManager, name]. The meter you are attempting to register has keys [cache, instance, name].
```

Thanks for the help for solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

Hi Use MeterRegistryCustomizer instead of HazelcastCacheMetrics

```
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MeterRegistryCustomizer;

@Bean
MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags() {
    return registry -> registry.config().commonTags("application", "MYAPPNAME");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but when I added appName into tags I still have error. Updated in question

Comment: are you adding the appName from spring props ? or odd coding ?

Comment: from environment properties

Comment: try implement like this, private void bindCacheToRegistry(String beanName, Cache cache) {
  Tag cacheManagerTag = Tag.of("cacheManager", getCacheManagerName(beanName));
  this.cacheMetricsRegistrar.bindCacheToRegistry(cache, cacheManagerTag);
 }                                                                                                                           https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/cache/CacheMetricsRegistrarConfiguration.java